# War external dependency overlay - move jars from WEB-INF/lib-new to WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-war-plugin

I am working on a maven project with a war external dependency (let's call this war dependency **WAR-DEP**)

After the build and during the package phase I am taking the content of **WAR-DEP** and merging it with the content of the current build using the overlay feature of the maven-war plugin.

In **WAR-DEP** we have some required jars in it's **WEB-INF/lib** folder so with the overlay we end up getting everything we need in our final war but our problem started when the project providing us with the **WAR-DEP** war added a new folder in the **WEB-INF/lib-new** and moved some of the jars we had before in the **WEB-INF/lib** folder to this new folder **WEB-INF/lib-new**.

After building with this new version of the **WAR-DEP** the overlay worked as expected so we ended up having two folders in the WEB-INF (lib and lib-new) and our application stopped working since this **WEB-INF/lib-new is not recognized by tomcat server**. So without changing the classpath on tomcat side is there a way I can move the content of lib-new into the lib folder before generating the war ? I mean for example during the overlay but I am not sure how to do this.
Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Which underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you use something like `/lib-new` ?? does not make sense... because it's not the default...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the app needs all the jars added into WEB-INF/lib-new to work properly but folder is not loaded in tomcat context at run time. tomcat only load the dependencies from WEB-INF/lib directory. My solution is the take all the jars we have in lib-new and put them in the lib folder during the overlay (maven package phase) but no idea how to achieve that. please feel free the suggest another fix if there is one. Thanks

Comment: @khmarbaise the war-dep is an external war (buid by a third party entity) so we don't have any control over it.

Comment: Is the set of third party jars static or do you get new versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maven-war-plugin` does not have required functionality, however `maven-dependency-plugin` [may help](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-filemapper.html), smth. like:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-lib-new</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>dep-group-id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dep-artifiact-id</artifactId>
                        <version>dep-version</version>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>WEB-INF/lib-new/*</includes>
                        <fileMappers>
                            <org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FlattenFileMapper/>
                        </fileMappers>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <overlays>
            <!-- current project -->
            <overlay/>
            <overlay>
                <id>dep-skip-lib-new</id>
                <groupId>dep-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>dep-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>WEB-INF/lib-new/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </overlay>
        </overlays>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```